# Best course of action for this prayer plant?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, watering

With the COVID-19, we had to leave our office plants unattended for several weeks. We used to have healthy Maranta, but someone took it outside at some point and it rained a lot. The outer pot did not have draining holes so the it was pretty harshly over watered.

It has unfortunately only two leaves left, and they do not unfurl during the day. What are my options?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do apart from giving it some tlc; you can cut off dead leaves, otherwise, water only when it needs it, as you usually would. A small amount of houseplant fertiliser might help to encourage it, but otherwise, just wait and see if it starts putting out new growth when it's had time to recover.  It certainly isn't completely dead yet.

Comment: Thanks! Should I cut the dead leaves above or below the leaf node?

Comment: Above, according to https://smartgardenguide.com/prayer-plant-care/ :)